# React Native WebView Not Opening from Email Deep Link in Simulator

Tags: react-native, email, webview, ios-simulator, deep-linking

> Unable to Open React Native WebView Using Deep Link from Email in iOS Simulator

I'm developing a `React Native` app with a `WebView` that should display a password reset page. This page is hosted locally during development `http://localhost:3000/reset-password`. The goal is to open this `WebView` in my app when a user clicks on a deep link in an email. The email is sent to the user whenever he tries to set his password. I did this using `AWS` and the link that is sent to the user to reset the password is the following:

> link:http://localhost:3000/reset-password?token=${jwt.sign({ data: userMatch }, config.app.secret, {expiresIn: "1h",
> algorithm: <jwt.Algorithm>config.app.algorithm})}

**What Works**

The `WebView` loads correctly when I manually navigate to it within the app.
Communication between my web content and `React Native` component is functional; I can navigate back to the Login screen from the WebView.

**What Doesn't Work**

When clicking the deep link from an email, the link opens in the browser outside of my app instead of navigating to the `WebView` within the app.

**My DeepLinking Configuration is found in App.tsx**

```js
const linking = {
  prefixes:["localhost:3000","yourapp://"],
  config:{
    screens:{
      // Reset:"reset-password",
      Local:"reset-password"
    }
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [initialURL, setInitialURL] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    Linking.getInitialURL().then((url:any) => {
      if (url) {
        setInitialURL(url);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <StatusBar  backgroundColor="white" barStyle="dark-content" ></StatusBar>
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
     <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Login' screenOptions={{ headerStyle :{
      backgroundColor: 'white',
    }}}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} initialParams={{ initialURL }} options={{headerShown:false}} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={MyTabs} options={{ headerShown: false}}/> 
    <Stack.Screen name="Reset" component={ResetPasswordScreen} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="Local" component={LocalWebViewScreen} options={{headerShown:false}} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </>
  )
}

const styles= StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:'#121212',
  }
})

export default App;
```

/// And this is the `LocalWebviewComponent` that renders my react web page running on localhost:3000

**LocalWebview.tsx**

```js
const LocalWebViewScreen = ({route}:any) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>>();
    const webViewRef = useRef(null);

    const handleMessage = (event:any) => {
        const message = event.nativeEvent.data
        if(message === "navigateBack"){
            console.warn("they are communicating")
            navigation.navigate("Login")
        }
    }
    const token = route.params?.jwt 
    const url = `http://localhost:3000/reset-password?token=${token}`;
  return (
  <WebView
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    ref={webViewRef}
    source={{ uri: url }} 
    onMessage={handleMessage}
   />
  );
};

export default LocalWebViewScreen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot test deep links on iOS simulator from e2e.
If you wanna test if your can handle your link use `npx uri-scheme open "exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/reset-password" --ios`

Docs are [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/#testing-with-npx-uri-scheme)